# How to do the SEO of angular website

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, prerender

I have a website in angularjs. I am using prerender.io for the SEO. But my website is still not crawlable by Google. What to do ?

My .htaccess file looks something like this.

# Handle Prerender.io
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "pPSyD3N1tOziIdRgQIwT"

RewriteEngine On

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slac$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

    # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpe$
```

```
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

     RewriteRule ^ - [L]
     #If does not matches take to index.html
    RewriteRule ^ index.html
```